# How to use jQuery slideDown() to display _almost_ all contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div within a div. On page load, they should both be hidden, then when I trigger the `slideDown()` function on the outer div, I want the inner div to remain hidden. How can I achieve this?

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.body').hide();
    $('.display').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.body').slideDown();
    });
});
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="display" href="#">Display Outer</a>
    <div class="body">
        Now displaying outer div
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a class="display" href="#">Display Inner</a>
            <div class="body">
                Now displaying inner div
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of it not working: http://jsfiddle.net/b7Tpt/

Comment: I don't get, what's the question. Your code works..

Comment: Same thing here, your code works just fine...

Comment: Your code seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/kddrT/. When the outer div is displayed the inner div is still hidden

Comment: Please see latest code sample. I updated it to be a better reflection of the code I am actually working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is the use of [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/). [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) would traverse all levels to find the matches while the [children](http://api.jquery.com/children) would travel single level. So use `find('.body:first')` or children('.body')

```
$(function(){
    $('.body').hide();
    $('.display').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.body:first').slideDown();
    });
});
```

[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b7Tpt/2/)

OR

```
$(function(){
    $('.body').hide();
    $('.display').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.wrapper').children('.body').slideDown();
    });
});
```

[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b7Tpt/2/)

Comment: Ah, the difference between `find()` and `children()` was the key. It was also important to remember that `children()` only travels one level deep so any selectors that were a second level deep needed to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
$('.display').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.body').slideDown();
});
```

I think `$(this).closest('.wrapper')` was moving up the DOM tree and finding the top most `wrapper` div then opening all the `body` classes it found underneath. Using `siblings` should get the element with a `body` class that is directly beneath the clicked link.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/pMgVj/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Kf6gk/